# Apache Camel Http Component - OutOfMemoryError

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-http

I am facing out of memory error on using the Apache camel Http component to download/stream a file from a public link to an external system (SharePoint). It seems the component internally is reading all of the files into memory at once. Can we do this without loading whole stream to memory? The route is quite simple.

```
  /**
     * Submit file to upload
     */
    from("direct:fetch-content-data-and-upload")

            .log("** Fetching file content from public link")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .toD("${header.CamelHttpUri}")

            .process(this.submitFileToUpload)

            .end();
```

The processor internally uses Graph Client SDK to submit Input Stream to upload in chunks. Error is thrown before it can reach the processor.

````
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onIdleExpired(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:160)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onIdleExpired(SslConnection.java:391)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:402)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:171)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.idleCheck(IdleTimeout.java:113)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: ... 3 common frames omitted
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3537) ~[na:na]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:100) ~[na:na]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at java.base/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:130) ~[na:na]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream.write(CachedOutputStream.java:101) ~[camel-support-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:206) ~[camel-util-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:161) ~[camel-util-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:156) ~[camel-util-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:152) ~[camel-util-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.doExtractResponseBodyAsStream(HttpProducer.java:547) ~[camel-http-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.extractResponseBody(HttpProducer.java:532) ~[camel-http-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateResponse(HttpProducer.java:332) ~[camel-http-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:291) ~[camel-http-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66) ~[camel-support-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.lambda$process$0(SendDynamicProcessor.java:197) ~[camel-core-processor-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$$Lambda$1001/0x000000d8016ec350.doInAsyncProducer(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.support.cache.DefaultProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(DefaultProducerCache.java:327) ~[camel-support-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:182) ~[camel-core-processor-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:477) ~[camel-core-processor-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:181) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:54) ~[camel-base-engine-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask.lambda$redeliver$2(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:914) ~[camel-core-processor-3.21.0.jar!/:3.21.0]
Aug  3 07:38:37 ip-172-31-9-176 web: at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryTask$$Lambda$994/0x000000d8016c1360.done(Unknown Source) ~[na:na] ```
````

Comment: I think that steam is transform/load total to create body to call "process" method, if you want to process as stream maybe you have to find another component.

Comment: Is not all the routes/components eventually land in a sort of processor? So not really sure why it would collect all stream data first. I am not even logging any information here.

Comment: When this.submitFileToUpload is call it create an exchange and a body with the steam maybe use a "to".

Comment: There seems to be no way of streaming the output of the HTTP component. I tried adding additional "to" route as well. HTTP component always seem to load the whole payload in memory. I had to use a standard Java URL to open the stream directly inside the processor. This does take care of memory issues.